# The meaning of "being raised right"

Tags: phrase-meaning

Google search results for [*being raised right quotes*](http://www.google.com/m?hl=en-US&ie=UTF-8&source=android-browser&q=being+raised+right+quotes)

From the link mentioned above, I found the word  "being raised right". What does this phrase mean in general?

Comment: It means the upbringing or the way one is brought up is correct or good.

Comment: Which part of this is confusing or unclear to you?  If I tell you that "to be raised" roughly means "how your parents taught you when you were growing up", does it make more sense?

Answer (score 2):

In this context:

Raising, is the process by which a child is cared for until adulthood. It is close to or synonymous with "rearing" or "parenting".

Now I'm not sure exactly which part of speech "**Raised**" is -- some past participle or something -- but it is often preceded by some part of the verb "to be", as in "to be raised" or, in this case "**Being** raised", which means something like "*The fact that we were* raised..."

Finally, "**Right**" is some positive valuation. It is close to or synonymous with "properly", or "correctly", or "well".

Thus, taking one of the examples returned from that URL; i.e. the one saying:

> Being raised right doesn't mean we won't make mistakes...

the meaning is something like:

> The fact that we were parented properly doesn't mean we won't make mistakes...

That said, that's a bit stilted as a translation. It would probably be more common to use yet another colloquial phrase and say:

> The fact that we were ***brought up*** properly doesn't mean we won't make mistakes...